# Error while loading shared libraries: No such file or directory even with path

Tags: unix, terminal, environment-variables, shared-libraries

I have just been introduced to open source and to give it a shot,i have downloaded the particular software and installed via the ubuntu terminal.The build of the software is present in the directory *./Downloads/squash*. No errors have been produced during the installation . When i execute the software, i receive the following error:

$ squash -L

> squash: error while loading shared libraries: libsquash0.7.so: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have tried to provide the path to **libsquash0.7.so**, but i receive the same error.
I have tried to search for solutions to the problem but have failed to do so, or may have overlooked some things.If a similar problem has been solved i request a link to its solution if not the exact solution itself.

Comment: From where did you download the software? Setting PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variables should usually solve these kind of issues.

Comment: Its an api called "squash",downloaded it from the site itself.The issue was resolved after i ran the software after changing the current directory, to the directory libsquash0.7.so was present in.So the question would now be, why did it not run when i provided a path to the directory ?